# Special characters or alt?

Tags: html, css

So I got this nicely written script from github for sortable nested items. And in the CSS I found this:

```
dd3-handle:before { content: '≡'; }
```

What is that inside the quotes and where can I find more.

Comment: It's one of the several hundred thousand characters to be found in Unicode. 

Comment: Look at a Character Map on your OS and find more.  ≡ is "identical to"

Comment: You can use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%E2%89%A1) for searching characters which Google doesn't accept.

Comment: You might find this useful for looking up special characters:  http://shapecatcher.com/

Answer (score 1):

#### ≡ equals identical to

The entity code for this is `&equiv;`

The number code is `&#8801;`

The hex code is `&#x2261;`

To find more, go to a website that has listings for "HTML Entities"

Comment: It should be noted that the preferred way of writing out special characters in CSS via the content property is with the hexidecimal number:  `content: "\2261"`.

Comment: @cimmanon, I don’t think any specification expresses such a preference.

Comment: cimmanon is right.  You can't use &equiv; in CSS because that would just display the exact 7-character string &equiv; rather than convert it into its entity.  It needs to be literal content.

Comment: I just verified that nothing works except as said cimmanon wrote: You must use
content:"\201c"; 
in the CSS definition or it doesn't work -- in IE and Chrome today at least.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff inside the quotes is just literal content to be displayed, as per the psuedo-selector, prior to the element's content. As for more, it can be whatever, but it's literal: that is to say, you can't shove some HTML in there and expect it to be treated as such by the browser, it won't be.

You can also use the `:after` pseudo element to do the obvious.

From [MDN re `content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content):

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.

Check out the link for more complex values, as I oversimplify here.